# Why is にも used here with the passive instead of simply も?

Tags: particle-に, particle-も

[image]

In the first line, the character comments that's he's really 詐欺師 and he skillfully deceived the third person (not in the scene anymore), not letting out he's in  激痛.

To which the other character comments, to my understanding "Then, if that's the case I'd like for you to be deceived as well."

I don't think "If that's the case I'd like for you deceive as well." given the なら and the person they were deceiving is no longer with them.

My reading seem to be that he wanted the character to also not notice/point out he's in extreme pain.

However, why is にも used here? Would もalone work given it's passive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is にも used here? Would も alone work given it's passive?

に is there because it's part of the [AにBして欲しい / AにBしていただきたい](https://guiadejapones.com/gramatica-jlpt/%E3%81%A6%E6%AC%B2%E3%81%97%E3%81%84-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%84-te-hoshii-significado/) construction (meaning "want A to do B"). When there is も and there is no risk of ambiguity, actually you can drop に and say AもBして欲しい instead of AにもBして欲しい, but it's better to keep this に in formal sentences.

Technically speaking, あなたに in あなたにも騙されていただきたい can modify either the passive part (騙される) or the wanting part (欲しい). That is, this phrase is ambiguous between "I want someone to be deceived also by you" and "I want also you to be deceived (by me)". In this context, the 詐欺師 is the speaker (チェズレイ), so the latter is the correct interpretation.

> My reading seem to be that he wanted the character to also not notice/point out he's in extreme pain.

That's possible, but it depends on the previous context. If there is a past episode where チェズレイ tried to deceive モクマ but it didn't work out, then the sentence may be about this episode.